# Fill array with all possible combinatios from another array

Tags: arrays, c, combinations

In one part of my program I have array of numbers from 0 to `n`. I need to find every possible combination of 2 and the first number must always be smaller than the second one. `n` is not given until other calculations are made so it has to be dynamically allocated.

And this list I need to put into some kind of `arr[][]`.

I know how to print such a list but cant figure out how to put it into array so I can work with those values later.

For example:

```
0 1 2 3
```

would be

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

void combinationUtil(int arr[], int n, int index, int data[], int i);

void printCombination(int arr[], int n)
{
    int data[2];

    combinationUtil(arr, n, 0, data, 0);
}

void combinationUtil(int arr[], int n, int index, int data[], int i)
{
    if (index == 2)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
            printf("%d ",data[j]);
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    if (i >= n)
        return;

    data[index] = arr[i];

    combinationUtil(arr, n, index+1, data, i+1);
    combinationUtil(arr, n, index, data, i+1);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8 ,9 ,10, 11, 12};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    printCombination(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *" first number must always be bigger than the second one"* does not line up with your example.

Comment: What is `combinationUtil` doing?

Comment: Oh yeah its meant to be smaller my bad